# Combine two dataframes with columns of different lines

Tags: python, pandas

I concatenated two dataframes like this:

```
df_1={'type1':[0,1,2],'type3':[89,90],'type3'=['cat','dog']}
df_2={'df_2_1':[90],'df_2_2':[98],'df_2_3':[9]}
```

`final=pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1, ignore_index=False, join='inner')`

However when I get the output I get this result:
(type1,ID,type3 belong to df_1; the other columns belong to df_2)

[image]

the desired output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please show an example of input + desired output - not in picture form, but as text data, so users here can reproduce it.

Comment: I solved this problem when I created the second dataframe. I just added index=[0] and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work based on your desired output -

```
final = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
```